# How to obtain the required output, I have tried with GROUP BY, but could not obtain what I want

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table

```
\d sales_girls

  Column   |         Type         | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------+----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id        | character varying(4) |           |          |
 f_name    | character varying(8) |           |          |
 sale      | integer              |           |          |
 sale_date | date                 |           |          |

SELECT * FROM p8.sales_girls;

  id  | f_name | sale | sale_date
------+--------+------+------------
 E001 | Linda  | 1000 | 2016-01-30
 E002 | Sally  |  750 | 2016-01-30
 E003 | Zindy  |  500 | 2016-01-30
 E001 | Linda  |  150 | 2016-02-01
 E001 | Linda  | 5000 | 2016-02-01
 E002 | Sally  |  250 | 2016-02-01
 E001 | Linda  |  250 | 2016-02-02
 E002 | Sally  |  150 | 2016-02-02
 E003 | Zindy  |   50 | 2016-02-02
(9 rows)
```

**intended output**

I want to select the rows having the maximum of each girl

```
  id  | f_name | sale | sale_date
------+--------+------+------------
 E002 | Sally  |  750 | 2016-01-30
 E003 | Zindy  |  500 | 2016-01-30
 E001 | Linda  | 5000 | 2016-02-01
(9 rows)
```

I have tried

```
SELECT id, f_name, MAX(sale), sale_date
FROM p8.sales_girls
GROUP BY f_name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
select id,f_name,sale,sale_date from (        
    select id,f_name,sale,sale_date,max(sale) OVER (PARTITION BY id) max_sale  from  sales_girls 
) a where sale=max_sale
```

But what's happen if Lynda has two lines with a sale of 5000 ?

if you want in this case the max date :

```
select id,f_name,sale,max(sale_date) sale_date from (         
select id,f_name,sale,sale_date,max(sale) OVER (PARTITION BY id) max_sale  from sales_girls 
    ) a where sale=max_sale
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: Look at the Laurenz Albe solution it seems simpler for same result , I don't use "distinct on" enough

Answer (score 1):

Use PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
       id, f_name, sale, sale_date
FROM p8.sales_girls
ORDER BY id, sale DESC;
```

Your table does not seem properly normalized, since `id` seems to identify a "sales girl".